# Is there a word or phrase that means "use other people's wifi or Internet service without consent"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word or phrase that means "use other people's wifi or Internet service without consent"? I think some people are able to use other people's wifi without consent even if they're password protected, is there a word that means exactly that? I don't know any word used to say that.

Comment: @Lambie Why not? There's a verb in English that means "throw (a frog) into the air from the end of a stick".

Comment: @userr2684291 - Your comment led me to [this M-W blog post](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/top-10-words-with-bizarre-meanings), an entertaining caution to anyone who thinks, "There can't be a word for ***that***."

Answer (score 54, accepted):

One word used is **piggybacking**, given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piggybacking_(Internet_access)) as

> Piggybacking on Internet access is the practice of establishing a wireless Internet connection by using another subscriber's wireless Internet access service without the subscriber's explicit permission or knowledge.

One definition of **piggyback** given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/piggyback) is

> **piggyback**
>   VERB
>
> **1.1** Link to or take advantage of (an existing system or body of work)
>   *they have piggybacked their own networks on to the system*

Comment: +1, I'm not so good at computers, so I'm wondering if *hacking* could go, just out of curiosity.

Comment: @LucianSava it is a *form* of hacking, but that has a more broad use. For example, hacking into a server does probably not involve wifi.

Comment: For what it's worth, this term is also listed at [netlingo.com](https://www.netlingo.com/dictionary/p.php), which is essentially an online computer dictionary.

Comment: Piggybacking is a mostly neutral term in this context, as it's entirely cromulent to say that *my neighbor lets me piggyback on his gigabit Internet connection*.

Comment: @chrylis You keep writing *this context,* but it's unclear what context you're talking about. What's your evidence that it's "mostly neutral"? Is *stealing* "mostly neutral" in some context because it's entirely cromulent to say *You need to stop letting me steal these brownies you made. They're making me fat*?

Comment: While wikipedia uses this term, I've never really heard it commonly in use.  Far more prevalent, imo, is the term "wi-fi squatting" or "wireless squatter".  See [WIRED : Is Wi-Fi Squatting Illegal?](https://www.wired.com/2011/03/pr-burning-wifi-squatting/), [PC-Mag : Wi-Fi Squatting](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/63042/wi-fi-squatting).  When I think of "piggybacking" I think of someone walking away from a public PC, leaving the browser or system logged in with their account that the "piggybacker" then proceeds to use.

Answer (score 59):

The quintessential idiomatic term in this context is **leech** (*vt*, or as *n* the person doing it). Per [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leech),

> 2. (figuratively) A person who derives profit from others in a parasitic fashion.

[Urban Dictionary's top definition](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=leech&defid=3101493) lists "parasite" and "freeloader" as synonyms.

**Leech** in this sense is very common slang in technical circles and especially file-sharing, where it refers specifically to downloading files but not staying online to share them. [A Google search for "leeching Wi-Fi"](https://www.google.com/search?q=leeching+wi-fi) turns up a full page of results describing the exact activity in the question.

Comment: I generally prefer "leech" in this case (and I definitely hear it more) especially because it differs from "piggyback" in that it emphasizes a dislike toward the act. "Piggybacking" sounds fairly neutral, whereas "leeching" definitely expresses the aforementioned parasitic behavior. (Compare "I don't mind you piggybacking on my wifi," to "I don't mind you leeching my wifi;" the latter sounds a little odd, IMO.)

Answer (score 26):

The best [American, maybe not British] English word for this is probably *mooching*. It specifically refers to using a resource that's not well-guarded, either without permission or overstepping intended level of permission, in a way that's annoying or inconvenient to others but not severe enough to be treated as theft. Other examples of mooching include:

- Consuming snacks from employee break area as meals.
- Dropping in a bank that has free lolipops for customers' children with no actual business to conduct, just to get lolipops.
- Consuming a roommate's food from their [section of the] refrigerator, or consistently consuming more than your fair share from food purchased jointly for use by oneself and roommates.
- Using a roommate's car that they always fill with gas.

The term mooching is also used fairly often for legitimate use of social welfare programs for their intended purposes, when the speaker either doesn't understand or doesn't accept those intended purposes.

Comment: Is it still mooching when the owner has made an attempt to protect it, by having a password?

Comment: @Barmar: I think people's opinions will differ, but rather than it being a disagreement over the meaning of the word or the right word to use, it's a disagreement over the kind/severity of offense that is. My view, from a security professional standpoint, is that wifi passwords are not an [effective] access control mechanism, rather a deterrent against mooching. This view is definitely more compelling when the password is widely known/shared to begin with (e.g. given out to patrons/customers or friends). It's less clear if the user resorted to brute-forcing or setting up MITM APs to get it.

Comment: I was going to say that it's not really mooching if they give out the password, but if the wifi is supposed to be for patrons only, you're technically mooching if you use it without actually buying anything.

Comment: @Barmar: That's why I characterized it as "without permission *or overstepping intended level of permission*". Another example of mooching is ordering a single plain coffee then sitting in the coffee shop all day using the wifi.

Comment: mooching only means that in US English. In British English it refers to a kind of apathetic state. So I would dispute the claim that this is the "best English word"

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks for the info. I incorporated that into my answer.

Answer (score 18):

One could say such people are *free riders*, a noun derived from *free ride*:

> 1 : a benefit obtained at another's expense or without the usual cost or effort

(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/free%20rider))

and in the same spirit (thanks @PeterJennings), *freeloaders*, derived from the verb *freeload*

> : to impose upon another's generosity or hospitality without sharing in the cost or responsibility involved

(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freeload))

which nicely 'rhymes' with upload & download, which is what you do when using the network.

These are certainly not limited to using WiFi, as @Lambie suggests.

Comment: Another possibility from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freeload) is "**freeload** : to impose upon another's generosity or hospitality without sharing in the cost or responsibility involved." Again, not confined to WiFi, but pleasingly appropriate!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that. It crossed my mind too but I somehow didn't bother looking it up.

Comment: Freeloading has a negative connotation— it emphasizes the cost.  Walking into a hotel lobby’s guest WiFi and using it for 30 seconds before leaving might not be “freeloading”.

Comment: The term has no relationship to Wi-Fi or Internet services, however. One could just as well suggest that taking a baby without permission is called *stealing.* And freeloading requires consent or an initial invitation or gift, which is obviously not at all what the OP asks about.

Comment: @whiskeychief The question is specifically asking about using the service without the owner's permission, in which a word with a negative connotation is entirely appropriate.

Comment: freeloading tends to describe antisocial but lawful behaviour, no?

Answer (score 11):

Honestly the word I have heard used for this is just "stealing". This is fairly common in everyday use, because "stealing" is a quite general term for taking something without authorization.

Comment: In mob-speak, it is "leveraging".

Comment: Yep... "I'm stealing my neighbour's WiFi". "Someone's stealing my WiFi"...

Answer (score 10):

### TL;DR

It's helpful to think about the way you're framing this. If you're viewing bandwidth or the Wi-Fi network as personal property, then the matching term or phrase should have a negative connotation that carries a sense of theft or unauthorized use.

### Some Common Terms

They might be “stealing bandwidth,” which is a limited resource on Wi-Fi networks. They may also be “trespassing” (in several senses of the word, and especially in the sense of unlawful transit of property).

Taking possession of another’s property (in this case, bandwidth) is “squatting.” The person squatting on the network is a “squatter.”

If it wasn’t an open network, then someone had to “hack” it or “crack” it to gain access. The former term is more common in colloquial speech, but the latter more strongly connotes “breaking” (or "breaking into") the system.

If it was an open network, and no money exchanged hands, then the unpaid use of the Wi-Fi would be “freeloading.” The one freeloading would therefore be a “freeloader.”

It's definitely worth pointing out the terms above are closely related, but aren't identical. For example, "trespassing" and "stealing" are both crimes, but stealing carries a stronger sense of criminal *intent*.

Comment: When the person has to crack/hack it's also called: Wardriving -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wardriving

Comment: As a legal sense in the UK its under the legal terms of "Computer Misuse" - it may also be covered by "Fraud", i.e. if you present yourself as a legitimate user to the system, you are fraudulently presenting credentials. one of the definitions of Computer Misuse *in the UK*, is unauthorised access or attempting unauthorised access. https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/crossheading/computer-misuse-offences

Comment: @acidjunk Wardriving is the process of searching for connections to use, not the use of them after they've been discovered.

Comment: “hack” it or “crack" it **or "spoof" it.** - The way in which, or *if*, the password was compromised will determine. - I'd like to point out that this is two different questions. The first doesn't have an answer because that's y'all's fault. The word for that is *comeuppance*.

Comment: @Barmar ...typically by *driving* around in a personal vehicle looking for open ones. Some people (such as myself actually) leave their wifi purposely open, in case someone needs one in an emergency. My daughter in High School had a friend who would make use of it on nights when his family was being abusive.

Comment: @T.E.D. If he's a friend, why don't you just tell him the password?

Comment: @Barmar - He probably wouldn't have. He was a friend of hers, but kind of shy. I had no idea this was going on until neighbors called the cops on him one night. And anyway, why would I go through the trouble to set up a password, just to pass it out freely? That's a lot of effort (and annoyance every time it has to be entered) for no gain.

Comment: @T.E.D. You're not passing it out freely, only to people you intentionally let into your home. Most home wifi devices don't put out a strong enough signal to be used outside the house, so passersby can't use it. I believe wardrivers use custom devices with extra-sensitive receivers to get around this.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, I know how locked wifi works, I just don't care to do it. If *you* want to go through all that extra effort with your house, that's your business I suppose, but I'm not so excited about stopping people from having internet access to bother with it.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to suggest the obvious: *thief*.

It clearly indicates the "without consent" part of the question.

Or perhaps the more specific term: *bandwidth thief*.

If a company is paying for Internet access by the megabyte then the person using it without permissions is certainly stealing. If the company pays a flat fee for a limited amount of bandwidth then the unapproved person is still stealing - if they use 200 MB of a company's 2GB plan, that is 200 MB the company is now deprived of using.

Comment: Thieving/stealing implies that something is taken from someone.  Depriving the original owner of having a thing.  This isn't the best word to describe what's happening where someone is using someone else's WiFi and not significantly impacting the owner from also using it.

Comment: @Brad: Software piracy has many cases where the copyright holder isn't significantly impacted, yet we still use the word "piracy" to describe the act. If someone stole the napkin on my desk, I wouldn't be significantly impacted, but it's still considered theft if I didn't give them permission. In both cases, the issue is whether it's moral and/or legal, not on whether the owner should really care.

Comment: @MichaelS yes and no.  Internet connectivity isn't an object or a non-renewable resource.  Nor in most cases is it something that you pay for in a quantized way.  The person who is paying for the access is still getting the access that they're paying for.  If the "bandwidth thief" is actually running them into bandwidth limitations or data caps that's a different situation but most commonly this would be a "no impact" vs "low impact" thing.

Comment: As an example, my cable provider (comcast) decided some time ago that they should make the router I was borrowing from them transmit a 2nd ssid that they provided access to for any other comcast customer.  They turned this "feature" on without notification or explicit consent.  When I called them about it the assured me that there would be zero impact to my network performance.  They're still doing this so presumably that argument has some legs (even if it's not 100% true in all circumstances).

Comment: The "thief" in this scenario isn't stealing anything from the person with the access.  They're actually stealing access from the ISP by using the other person's connection.  That other person is more accurately described as an accessory than as a victim.

Comment: Back in the day in the UK Phone hackers/Phreaks where charged with stealing her majesties electricity

Comment: If they use $1000 worth of traffic and I am invoiced for it, then yes, something is being taken from me.

Comment: Same case if the upstream connection is (eg because it is satellite internet or 4G) volume limited. Use up the contingent and the owner of the WiFI could be terminated, invoiced, have his quality of service throttled, etc....

Comment: I don't doubt that those who steal wifi bandwidth are committing acts of thievery.  However, it seems like the OP is looking for a _specific_ word that describes this specific act.